# How do I make this delegation in c++ class?

Tags: c++

Instruction: A Length() function that returns the length of the line. Note that you can use the distance function on the embeddedPoint objects to calculate the length. This mechanism is called “delegation”.

Point and Line are two different classes.

in Line class, I write the Length function, **but I don't know how to define it by using this delegation:**

```
double Length() const; // the length function
```

In Point Class, I create the distance function in .h and define it in.cpp

```
double Distance(const Point& p) const; // constant reference
```

```
// Define Distance (Point p) that calculates the distance to another point

double Point::Distance(const Point& p2) const {
    double x_distance = (m_x - p2.m_x) * (m_x - p2.m_x);
    double y_distance = (m_y - p2.m_y) * (m_y - p2.m_y);

    return std::sqrt(x_distance + y_distance);

}
```

Comment: A `line` should have a start point and an end point. So in the `length` function you can do `return end_point.Distance(start_point);`, when `end_point` and `start_point` are the `Point` objects.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know is:

1. A line can be defined as 2 points.
2. The length of a line is the distance between the two points defining it.

In your case, I assume the `Line` class does have 2 `Point` members. Since the `Point` class already implements a way to calculate the distance between another point, you may use it to calculate the distance between the 2 `Point` members of `Line`.

---

**Example to illustrate**:

*example.h*

```
#include <cmath>

class Point
{
    private:
        double x, y;

    public:
        Point(int px, int py);
        Point(const Point &) = default;

        double distance(const Point & p) const;
};

class Line
{
    private:
        Point p1, p2;

    public:
        Line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);
        Line(const Point & pt1, const Point & pt2);

        double length() const;
};
```

*example.cpp*

```
#include "example.h"

Point::Point(int px, int py) : x(px), y(py)
{}

double Point::distance(const Point & p) const
{
    return std::sqrt((p.y - y)*(p.y - y) + (p.x - x)*(p.x - x));
}

Line::Line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) : p1(x1, y1), p2(x2, y2)
{}
Line::Line(const Point & pt1, const Point & pt2) : p1(pt1), p2(pt2)
{}

double Line::length() const
{
    return p1.distance(p2); // Delegate the length calculation to Point::distance()
}
```

In this example, the delegation happens there:

```
double Line::length() const
{
    return p1.distance(p2); // Delegate the length calculation to Point::distance()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I want to do the getter and setter functions for the Line as this, are those formats correct? `// the getter, accessing the function
Point P1() const;
Point P2() const;

// the setter, set point p1 and p2
void P1(const Point& p1);
void P2(const Point& p2);`Then for the default constructor and the parameterized constructor, what should I write then? How should I do an overloaded getter and setters for both two points? @Fareanor

Comment: @ChristineZhou Yes it's correct, but I won't recommend you to use overloads, it would be confusing. It would be better to use the names `p1()` and `p2()` for the getters and `setP1()` and `setP2()` for the setters (no overload, be explicit about what the function does). Overloads are meant for several versions of the same operation (requiring different parameters, but the task remains the same). Getters and setters are opposite operations, using overloads to define them would be too confusing.

Comment: I already have written the parametrized constructor, you can just take the same. For the default constructor, feel free to do as you wish. If you don't really care, you can `default` it ^^